# Phonegap Filetransfer undefined

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Am testing my phonegap app in a web browser and get the following in console:

```
'FileTransfer' is undefined
```

Have tried the following:

1) installing the plugins, the plugin list shows:

```
cordova-plugin-file 2.0.0-dev "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.0.0-dev "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.0.0-dev "Capture"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File"
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.5.0 "File Transfer"
```

2) Added following lines to config.xml

```
<feature name="File"><param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" /></feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer"><param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" /></feature>
```

3) Tried including the js files on the html page
4) Have read that FileTransfer can only be called after the device is ready,
but the function is called on a button click - this happens well after deviceready.

Have read most posts about this issue, but am now really stuck - please advise TQ

```
 //js
function uploadFile_S3(vidfile) {
var filetype = vidfile.type;
var filename_orig = vidfile.name;
var deferred = $.Deferred(),
    ft = new FileTransfer(),
    options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = filename;
    options.fileName = filename;
    options.mimeType = filetype;
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.params = {
        "key": filename,
        "AWSAccessKeyId": 'XXX',
        "acl": 'public-read',
        "policy": policyBase64,
        "signature": signature,
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    };

    ft.upload(imageURI, s3URI,
        function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e);
        },
        function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e);
        }, options);

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: Plugins works in mobile plataform apps not in web browsers.

Comment: That explains it TQ - can anyone tell how can you debug issues with plugins - do you need a mac?